# is user defined value equal to server side value?

Tags: php, jquery

if i set

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="<?php echo $origValue; ?>">
```

and use a function with this

```
$('#myinput').val('i change the value');
```

will my php variable value be change like

```
$origValue="i change the value";
```

and use that variable to different input like

```
<input type="text" id="secondText" value="<?php echo $origDate; ?>">
```

and it will show the same value??
if not, how can i do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - if you change the value on the client side, the original PHP value will not be changed. You seem a little confused about the relationship between client and server side.

The PHP is executed first to generate the HTML response. Once this is complete, the HTML is sent to the client, which then allows JavaScript to work on it. The two (JS & PHP) can never directly affect each other without a request being made back to the server.

Therefore, if you change the `val()` of the input in JS you would need to post that data back to your PHP page, either using a standard `form` element or an AJAX request.

Comment: Then how am i supposed to get the value of input (while in keyup) and make it the value of a php variable because i want my input to have pre-type value. Ex. I type "my name" in the first textbox, then i want that all other text box will start with "my name"

Comment: Then put a handler on the `keyup` event of the first textbox which changes the value of all the other textboxes to what was typed in, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hc3znfmc/

Answer (score 0):

Is it really that hard to actually 'try it' and find out yourself? It wouldn't take very long..

No it would not change dynamically. The $origValue is already set when the page loads and cannot be updated with jQuery like that. The variable is set when the page loads and cannot be changed.